# Connect Nodejs to MS SQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database-connection, vds

[I have this kind of error connecting database to nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OtNw.png)

MS SQL running on VDS server and IP is correct port default but it can't connect with database connection and everything is checked fully working I have game server on that VDS and also working perfectly database connected and everything now I wanted to create web for my server and couldn't figured how to fix this can anyone help me?

I asked Chat GBT about this problem it told me 5 ways to check and checked everything was normal

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76547381/edit) your question to include the complete error message as text, not screen shot(s). Images and screen shots are not indexable/searchable so answering a question based on images and screen shots would not assist anyone else in the community experiencing the same problem. Putting the core of your question into images and screenshots is also decidedly anti-mobile and will limit the number of people who can read and answer your question. You should also include the relevant section of Node code since this could be an issue with pooling.